# Should \urlstyle go into preamble or document body?

Tags: urls, preamble, body

Here is my LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
Example: \url{http://www.example.com/}
\end{document}
```

My question is about `\urlstyle{same}`.

I have two questions.

1. Give a man a fish: I have put `\urlstyle{same}` in preamble. But putting it in the document body also works fine. What is the right place to put it?
2. Teach a man to fish: In future, how can I understand (from documentation or by other means) whether a command should go into the preamble or document body?

Comment: I don't think there's a general rule, but I'd say that commands that can change a certain behavior only once, do not produce any text, or are specified to belong to the preamble have to go to the preamble. `\urlstyle` is a command that *switches* the current *typesetting* style, and I'd expect it to do its job both in the preamble and document body. Note that the command comes from the package `url` that is missing in your minimal example.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I thought the `\url` command comes from the `hyperref` package which I have included in my example. Or is it that the `hyperref` package internally includes the `url` package?

Comment: @LoneLearner `hyperref` requires `url`, but `url` can be used without `hyperref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command in both places. Put it in the preamble if you want to change the general style for (allmost) all url's. Use it in the document (or inside definition of commands like \path, \email etc) if you want to change the style locally for some url's only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
Example: \url{http://www.example.com/}

a specially formatted url {\urlstyle{tt}\url{learner@example.com}}
\end{document}
```